# JavaScript getting innerHtml for all text nodes in nested elements

Tags: javascript, textnode

Need to process text inside uncertain layers of nested nodes using following function:

```
function processTextNodesIn(elem) {
  if (elem) {
    for (var nodes = elem.childNodes, i = nodes.length; i--;) {
      var node = nodes[i], nodeType = node.nodeType;
      if (nodeType == 3) {
        console.log("innerHtml = " + node.innerHTML);
      }
    }
    else if (nodeType == 1 || nodeType == 9 || nodeType == 11) {
      processTextNodesIn(node);
    }
  }
}
```

}
Text could be inside multiple `<p></p>` , `<div></div>` , `<li></li>` .
But the content found is all "undefined".
What did I do wrong?

Update:
Tried innerText(textContent as well) as @patrick suggested, still prints undefined.

Comment: Your code currently results in a SyntaxError. Can you make sure you post your actual code?

Comment: [Text nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) do not have an `innerHTML` property, to get the text use `textContent`

Comment: Can you not get the text content of all nested elements using `elem.textContent` of the parent element?

Comment: textContent and innerText behave the same. I would like to make some of text by add html formating to text.